# Ongoing Notification RemoteServiceException - Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification

Tags: android

I've clicked every SO link I could find on this issue but none seem to fit right.

here's the full error:

```
Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package my.package.name: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification(pkg=my.package.name user=UserHandle{0} id=328 tag=null key=0|my.package.name|328|null|10243: Notification(pri=2 contentView=my.package.name/0x7f040049 vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x22 color=0x00000000 vis=PUBLIC semFlags=0x0 semPriority=0))
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1813)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

I've learned, in my searching, that ID references can change when app upgrades but this error doesn't seem to point to a drawable resource or anything like that, it looks like the issue is on the layout file but I'm not sure what the problem is there.

Here's the layout file defined by **contentView=[my.package.name]/0x7f040049**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:paddingRight="6dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/notification_weather_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/notification_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notification_weather_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/notification_weather_icon"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/notification_weather_icon"
        android:fontFamily="@string/roboto_thin"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        tools:text="40*" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/notification_weather_text"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/notification_weather_text"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/weather_type_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2.5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="bottom">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/notification_weather_type"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:fontFamily="@string/roboto_light"
                android:gravity="start|bottom"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:maxWidth="200dp"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                tools:text="Overcast" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/notification_weather_location"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/notification_weather_type"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/notification_weather_type"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:fontFamily="@string/roboto"
                android:gravity="end|bottom"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:minWidth="36dp"
                android:paddingBottom="1dp"
                android:textColor="@color/ongoing_notification_small_text_color"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                tools:text="San Fransisco" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/weather_location_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingTop="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/notification_weather_precip"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/notification_weather_time"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/notification_weather_time"
                android:fontFamily="@string/roboto"
                android:gravity="top|start"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/ongoing_notification_small_text_color"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                tools:text="Precip 40%" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/notification_weather_time"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/notification_weather_precip"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="@string/roboto"
                android:gravity="top|end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/ongoing_notification_small_text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/gallery_grid_update_time_text_size"
                tools:text="4.00pm" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help identifying the root of this issue would be GREATLY appreciated

Comment: Did you find already a solution? I get the same crash but only on Samsung phones running Android 7.0 it seems.

Comment: unfortunately not.  Still hoping to find one some day

Comment: Any news on this problem?

Comment: It looks like the Chromium team had a similar issue 
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=831220
It sounds like a device specific implementation bug.  I would suggest setting the resource in code behind and catch the exception if doesn't find the resource.